# Screened Coulomb Potential effect on Hydrogen

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, perturbation-theory, hydrogen

How does a screened coulomb potential affect the ground state energy of hydrogen atom? Just by looking at the perturbed potential, can we make a prediction about the energy shift?

The screened Coulomb potential is

$$V'(r)=\frac {e^2}{4π\epsilon}\,\frac 1 r \, exp\left(-\, \frac r {r_0}\right).$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shift in the ground state of hydrogen](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/396000/)

Comment: If $r_0\gg a_0$ where $a_0$ is the Bohr radius, then you can expand the exponential in powers of $r/r_0$, so you end up having to evaluate the expectation value of the radius, which is $\dfrac{3}{2}  a_0$.

Comment: It is not clear to me if you mean a hydrogen atom perturbed by a locally close atom represented by a screened coulomb potential or if you mean calculating hydrogen with a screened coulomb potential instead of a bare coulomb potential for the nucleus. The second option does not make sense physically as neutral hydrogen only has one electron so there are no others to screen the nuclear potential